# I am trying to copy file from remote server to local machine

Tags: linux, scp

I get this error:

> ssh: connect to host ' my ip addr ' port 22: Connection refused

I am try ing to copy a csv file, from REMOTE SERVER to my computer, using SCP command

This is my code:

```
scp remote_server_username@remote_server_ip_addr:'path/to/file/i_want to copy' my_local_computer_username@ip_addr:'path_to file/where/i_want_to_save'
```

Comment: Can you do a plain SSH onto the remote?

Comment: Are you running this command on the local system, or on the remote system, or elsewhere?

Comment: I am using from local system

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync as an alternative. It is mostly for syncing purposes, but works well though.

```
rsync -avzh --stats --progress remote_user@remote_ip_address:/path/  localpath
```

To add ssh options:

```
rsync -e "ssh -P $port_value" remote_ user@remote_ip:/path/  localpath
```

The --stats and --progress switches are useful to display real time info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the sshd service status. It should be running. For Centos/RedHat try

**# systemctl status sshd**

2. Check in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file for any blocks
3. Check the firewall
4. Make sure your local computer is available to your remote machine. Try a ping test.